# New API for G Suite Admin Console?

Tags: api, google-admin-sdk

Is there New API replacing the current API:
https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/admin-settings/

If not, why are they removing such a feature?

> Warning: The Admin Settings API is deprecated and is scheduled to be sunset on October 30, 2017.

In addition, the current API does not support the full functions of the G Suite Admin console. For example, there is nothing on **Inbound Mail Gateway** and nothing on **Managing API Access in the Security Settings**

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Since it is schedule to be sunset on October 30, 2017, the Google still has 7 months to annonce if they will replace it with another API or they will totally shut down this API. I suggest you to always check the [Google Developers Blog](https://developers.googleblog.com/) about the announcement for their API release and updates.

For more information, check these blogs:

- [Saying Goodbye to the GData Admin Settings API](https://gsuiteupdates.googleblog.com/2016/08/saying-goodbye-to-gdata-admin-settings.html)
- [Google to Sunset GData Admin Settings API](https://www.programmableweb.com/news/google-to-sunset-gdata-admin-settings-api/2016/08/17)

Comment: Thank you for the answer